# Interface/type with a removed property

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I've tried creating many different `interface`s and `type`s, combining unions and intersections in different ways, but all have failed.

I have an interface with some properties:

```js
interface A {
    name: string;
    property: number;
    // many many more...
}
```

I want to create a new interface (or type, I do not care at this point) based on `A` which has `name` removed and some other properties added, resulting in:

```js
interface B {
    property: number;
    age: number;
    // everything else that A had, except name
}
```

How would I do that using the intersection/union or other possibilities of TypeScript?

I have even tried creating an intersection between `A` and another interface where `name?: never;` to get rid of that field, but then how can I add other properties?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Omit<A, 'name'>&{other properties}`

Answer (score 0):

```
interface A {
    name: string;
    property: number;
    foo: string;
}

// Get rid of name property
type AWithoutName = Omit<A, "name">;

// Now use the type to get all of A without name
const foo: AWithoutName = { property: 2, foo: "hello" }

// extend this type to add more props without name
interface AddMoreToA extends AWithoutName {
  bar: string;
}

// use in this way
const bar: AddMoreToA = { property: 2, foo: "hello", bar: "world" }
```